# How to scroll to a particular DIV on a Razor View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to build a sample e-commerce website using MVC and I have a a page which is like the summary page and I have few edit links on the page, which are Html.ActionLink , but what I am trying achieve here is when user clicks on the hyper link it should take the user to the page and  also to a particular DIV on the page. Any suggestions on how to achieve this

Comment: Add an `id` attribute to the `<div>` and then use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492938(v=vs.118).aspx) of `Html.ActionLink()` where you include a fragment

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `id` attribute to element you wish to bring into view and then use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492938(v=vs.118).aspx) of `Html.ActionLink()` which accepts a `fragment` (anchor name). For example, in the view your navigating to

```
<div id="someID">
  ....
</div>
```

and in the view that you want to navigate from

```
@Html.ActionLink("link Text", "actionName", "controllerName", null, null, "someID", null, null)
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke

Comment: Hi @Stephen, I have a situation now where this solution is not working, I have mentioned the ID's for the DIV and when I use this overloaded method on Html.ActionLink it is not taking  me to that section on the page.

Comment: Are you saying this is working sometimes but not in other situations? (you have not accepted the answer so not sure if you did ever get it working). If that's the case, you really need to as a new question showing the relevant code and the context in which it is being used

Answer (score 1):

```
//Bind your Html.ActionLink with 'id' parameter like   
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Link1", "Edit", new {Id=1})   
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Link2", "Edit", new {Id=2})


//Controller   
public ActionResult Edit(int? Id)   
        {   
            switch (Id)   
            {   
                case 1:   
                    ViewBag.Position= "Link1";   
                    break;   

                case 2:   
                    ViewBag.Position= "Link2";   
                    break;    

             }    
            return View("YourView");   
        }    

//View    

//In Razor view, put Link1 to Link3 in separate DIVs with ID like <div Id="Link1">..</div>,<div Id="Link2">    

 $(document).ready(function () {   
if ('@ViewBag.Position' != "") {   
            $('html, body').animate({    
             scrollTop: $('@ViewBag.Position' ).offset().top     
            }, 2000);    
        }     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be your action Link

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText","ActionName", new {divId = "ScroolToDivId"})
```

in controller you will have action for the above mentioned link.

```
public ActionResutl ActionName(String divId){
  yourModel objYourModel = new yourModel();
  objYourModel.ScrollToDiv = divId
  return View("ViewName", objYourModel);
}
```

In your view you will have the following.

```
@model yourModel
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ScrollToDiv)

<script>
 var ScrollToDiv = document.getElementsByName("ScrollToDiv");
 if(ScrollToDiv && ScrollToDiv.Value != ''){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#" + ScrollToDiv.Value).offset().top
    }, 2000);
 }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Yagensh, but couldn't use this as I will not be able to add a new parameter in to the Action method